# How to restore postgreSQL from dump file to AWS?

Tags: python, django, postgresql, amazon-web-services

I have PostgreSQL dump file in my local environment, and I want
to restore it on AWS server where Django app was deployed.

I think I should upload the dump file to AWS server but I don't know
where it should be uploaded to and how to restore it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, copy your file from your local environment to AWS using `scp` command

e.g

```
scp -i /directory/to/abc.pem mydump.sql user@ec2-xx-xx-xxx-xxx.compute-1.amazonaws.com:/tmp/
```

where `abc.pem` is your private aws key. `mydump.sql` is your dump file and `/tmp/` is the path where the dump file will be copied

Once the file is copied to your AWS /tmp folder or whatever location you use, Next you need to restore it to your database e.g using

```
./pg_restore -U postgres -p 5432 -d yourdatabase < mydump.sql
```

Answer (score 0):

Use pgrestore to restore your database.

Link : https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/app-pgrestore.html

Inorder to get a dump of your database use pgdump.

Link : https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/app-pgdump.html